# UICollectionView + Nib popViewControllerAnimated causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift

In my ViewController with iOS 8, I have UIView which contains a `UICollectionView`, like this:

[image]

The `UICollectionView` is created successfully using Nibs, like this:

```
  collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
```

and later refreshed via

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

All this is fine. However, when I try to go back to previous view via `navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`, I get the prevalent `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

I did some research and have these defensive code, but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
 override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        collectionView.dataSource = nil
        collectionView.delegate = nil
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    }

    deinit {
        collectionView.dataSource = nil
        collectionView.delegate = nil
        collectionView = nil
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are force unwrapping `navigationController`, so my first instinct would be to check if that really exists. What happens if you change the `!` to a `?`?

Comment: I have some code which I didn't show that checks for navigationController for nil. So that wasn't the problem. In fact, if I don't call 'reloadData', the pop works fine. Do I need to deregister nibs?

Comment: Could you post some more code, and highlight the line where the bad access occurs?

Comment: I couldn't figure out why, so I started a new class from scratch and the problem now disappears, maybe a Xcode 6 bug? Not sure. Thanks Bob though.